# declare variable outside of the foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net

In for loop case I can declare the index outside the for statement. For example, instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { }
```

I can do:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { }
```

Now in compare to foreach loop, I have to declare the variable inside the loop:

```
foreach (string name in names) { }
```

And I cannot do something like:

```
string name;
foreach (name in names) { }
```

The reason this bothers me is that after the loop I want to use the variable "name" again. In case of foreach loop the variable "name" can't be used since it outside of the foreach scope, and I cannot declare another variable with the same name since it declared before in the same scope.

Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you can do:

```
string name = null; // You need to set a value in case the collection is empty
foreach (string loopName in names)
{
    name = loopName;
    // other stuff
}
```

Or more likely:

```
string name = null; // You need to set a value in case the collection is empty
foreach (string loopName in names)
{
    if (someCondition.IsTrueFor(loopName)
    {
        name = loopName;
        break;
    }
}
```

If the contents of the foreach loop is *just* to find a matching element - which at least *sounds* likely - then you should consider whether LINQ would be a better match:

```
string name = names.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Fred"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Using LINQ can often make code which is basically trying to find something a *lot* simpler to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in foreach loops.  You are creating and using a range variable whose scope is limited to the foreach query.

If you need to use an individual name from within the names collection then you can assign it to a value outside of the foreach loop:

```
foreach(string name in names)
{
    if(name == someCondition)
        someVariable = name;
}
```

Comment: the OP mentioned that name remains on scope beyond the body of foreach, is that true?

Comment: @Shamim.  In my example, the variable name will not be in scope outside of this foreach loop.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess the OP is wrong about not being able to use "name" again.

Comment: @Shamim, you couldn't have another variable called name within the loops parent scope.  But outside of that, such as another method for example, then yes you could have another variable called name.

Comment: @Darren Young: I don't need the value but a variable with the same name.

Comment: @Naor, then no you cannot do this.  But you can name the variable within the loop anything you want really(within reason) as it is only in scope within that loop.  You could, for example, name it nameLoop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

```
string name;
foreach (var tmp in names) { name = tmp; }
```